# Characterisation of complete riemannian manifolds using divergent curves.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a riemannian manifold. Then $M$ is complete iff each divergent curve in $M$ has no finite length (a curve $\gamma : [0 , 1) \to M$ is divergent if for each compact $K \subset M$ there exists $t \in [0 , 1)$ such that $\gamma([0 , 1)) \cap K = \emptyset$.

I have shown that if $M$ is complete then each divergent curve in $M$ has no finite length. But how can I prove the converse?

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your definition of divergent.

Comment: what do you mean with typo?

Comment: Typographical error. You probably meant $\gamma(t) \not\in K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the converse, assume that $M$ is not complete, and let's find a divergent curve with finite length. By incompleteness, there is an inextendible geodesic $\alpha\colon [0,b) \to M$, with $b<+\infty$. We claim that $\alpha$ is already divergent: indeed, if there is a compact $K\subseteq M$ with $\alpha(t) \in K$ for all $t \in [0,b)$, we may take an increasing sequence $(t_n) \subseteq [0,b)$ with $t_n \to b$ and pass to a subsequence to assume that $\alpha(t_n) \to p$ and $\alpha'(t_n) \to v$ for some $p \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$. With this in hands, we may pick $\epsilon > 0$ small enough and extend $\alpha$ to a geodesic $\widetilde{\alpha}\colon [0,b+\epsilon) \to M$ by $$  \widetilde{\alpha}(t) = \begin{cases} \alpha(t), &\mbox{ if }t\in[0,b) \\ \exp_p((t-b)v), &\mbox{ if }t \in [b,b+\epsilon)\end{cases},   $$contradicting the inextendability of $\alpha$. And if $\alpha$ has constant speed $c$, clearly $L[\alpha] = cb<+\infty$, concluding the proof. Note that we may reparametrize this $\alpha$ to something whose domain is $[0,+\infty)$, but the length and the property of being divergent remain both unchanged.

Comment: does such compact really exist?

Comment: The definition of divergent curve, roughly speaking, says that "for every compact, the curve escapes the compact". If there's no such compact, this statement is vacuously true. The negation of "for all $x$, $P(x)$ holds" is "there is $x$ such that $\neg P(x)$". There's no problem here.

Comment: why is $\alpha$ divergent?

Comment: Please read the answer very slowly, this is already explained there: if $\alpha$ were not divergent, it would be extendible.